# header and c files function name doesn't match - c

Tags: c, header, header-files

I was reading code, as someone told me to - *learn to read codes*.

So in a `c` project, I found these two files very specifically:

- `some_header.h`
- `some_header.c`

In `some_header.h` there was a function prototype called `void DoSomething(void)`

But in the `some_header.c` the function was written like `void do_something(void)`.

**Why is that ?**

Comment: They are different functions.

Comment: I looked up for `DoSomething` in `.c` files and `do_something` in `.h` files, but I couldn't find any

Comment: There is no requirement that a prototype defined in a header must be implemented in a C file with the same base name.  It can be implemented anywhere.  Or it might not be used.  There's also no requirement that a function defined in a source file is exposed in a header.  Anyway, does the code you have even compile?  If you want an actual answer, you need to post a proper example.

Comment: You will have to ask the one who wrote the code

Comment: Agree with @paddy. The best way to find out would be to compile the code and debug or check the flow of program. You will get to know what all functions are being used.

Comment: Make a [mre] of the described code being successfully compiled. If it isn't successfully compiled the question is meaningless. If it is successfully compiled then making the MRE will give you the answer. The concept of an MRE is normally only applicable to misbehaving code, it does apply here however because the observed "strange" behaviour is that it **is** compiled successfully.